# Size Above Depth and size below Depth

Tags: java, size, binary-search-tree

I am a beginner of Java, and i was trying to write a code to count the number of nodes whose depth is smaller than a given depth and number of nodes whose depth is bigger a given depth.

```html
public static int sizeAboveDepth(Node t, int k) {
    // TODO: Complete this method.
    if (t == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (t.key > k)
      return (sizeAboveDepth(t.left, k - 1) + sizeAboveDepth(t.right, k - 1) + 1);
    else {
      return sizeAboveDepth(t.left, k - 1) + sizeAboveDepth(t.right, k-1);
    }
  }

  // EXERCISE 6: The method "sizeBelowDepth" is described above.
  // The number of nodes in the tree "below" depth k (not including k)
  // include node n if depth(n) > k.
  public static int sizeBelowDepth(Node t, int k) {
    // TODO: Complete this method.
    if (t == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (t.key > k)
      return (sizeBelowDepth(t.left, k-1) + sizeBelowDepth(t.right, k-1) + 1);
    else {
      return sizeBelowDepth(t.left, k-1) + sizeBelowDepth(t.right, k-1);
    }
  }
```

so is there anyone can help me to fix it? I am kind of crazy about it now~~

Comment: What, do you think, has the Node.key to do with the depth of a node?

Comment: i know it it worry but i do not know any other way to do it

Comment: Can you describe your Node class? I think you don't need to alter the K value, you might make it a static value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sizeAboveDepth(Node t, int depth, final int k) {
  if ( t != null && depth < k){
    return sizeAboveDepth( t.left, depth+1, k) + 
           sizeAboveDepth( t.right, depth+1, k) + 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }   
}

public static int sizeBelowDepth(Node t, int depth, final int k) {
  if (t == null) {
    return 0;
  }
  int below = sizeBelowDepth(t.left, depth+1, k) + 
              sizeBelowDepth(t.right, depth+1, k);
  if (depth > k){
    below++;
  }
  return below;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int sizeAboveDepth(Node t, int depth, static int k) {
    // TODO: Complete this method.
    if (t == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (depth < k)
      return (sizeAboveDepth(t.left,depth+1, k ) + sizeAboveDepth(t.right, depth+1, k) + 1);
    else {
      return 0
}   
}

public static int sizeBelowDepth(Node t, int depth,static int k) {
    // TODO: Complete this method.
    if (t == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (depth > k)
      return (sizeBelowDepth(t.left, depth+1, k) + sizeBelowDepth(t.right, depth+1, k) + 1);
    else {
      return sizeBelowDepth(t.left,depth++, k) + sizeBelowDepth(t.right,depth++, k);
    }   }
```

I'm not sure, but I think this can help you.